# Intellij not wrapping on typing

Tags: intellij-idea

In IntelliJ Ultimate 2020.1.4, if the length of the line of an '***if condition***' is more than 120 characters, while typing, it does not automatically wrap. What options should I change to achieve auto wrap on typing.

The image below shows the visual guide at 120 characters.

I have the following code style options

```
Hard wrap at: 120,
Wrap on typing: Yes,
Visual guides: Default: 120,
Ensure right margin is not exceeded: check marked
Hard wrap at 120 columns. Wrap on typing is check-marked
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you please share idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...") after restarting IDE?

Comment: Here is the idea.log file after restarting IDE

https://www.dropbox.com/s/41ef5xvqrwwflrw/idea.log?dl=0

Comment: Please try to temporarily disable custom plugins: "Loaded custom plugins: IdeaVim (0.58), ANSI Highlighter (1.2.4), Lombok (0.30-2020.1), Save Actions (2.0.0), IdeaExActionBar (0.0.3), File Watchers (201.8538.6), CamelCase (3.0.3), Live Edit (201.7223.18), Styled Components & Styled JSX (1.1.2), ESLint (1.0.36), deep-js-completion (2020.06.22.001), Relative Line Numbers (1.0.1) "

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that the formatter does not break long lines? Check Settings / Project Settings / Code Style / Wrapping.

Update: in later versions of IntelliJ, the option is under Settings / Editor / Code Style. And select Wrap when typing reaches right margin.

Comment: I do already have 'wrap when typing reaches right margin' check-marked as shown in the image of my original post. 

While typing, i expect it to wrap automatically when it reaches 120 characters.